# Laravel Eloquent - Conditionally eager load relations based on parent table's field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.8

These are my tables:

```
# Property
-id
-type[featured,standard]
-and others fields

# Meta
-id
-property_id
-and others fields
```

I have already set eloquent relation (hasOne)
And, what i am trying to achieve is to conditionally load meta relation for only properties which has type = "featured".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a query using **Property Model**

```
Property::with('meta')->where('type','featured')->get();
```

And if you run a query behalf of **Meta model**.

In this query, You'll get metas which `property` type has `featured`

```
Meta::whereHas('property', function($q){
    $q->where('type','featured');
})
```

**Edit:** Your answer is right, but what if i want to get all properties both featured and standard with meta for featured ones.

You want to get all `Property` with `meta` than this query will return `Property` with `meta`;

```
Property::with('meta')->get();
```

You need to use **eager loading** for this.

```
    $properties= Property::all();;
    $properties->where('type','featured')->load('meta');
    dd($properties);
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but what if i want to get all properties both featured and standard with meta for featured ones.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but what i meant was to get both types of properties but load meta relation only for featured, not for standard.

Comment: You need to use **eager loading** for this. check updated answer.